# How to fix Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () for firebase authentication with Email and Password?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to do firebase authentication with Email and Password. For the first time, I succeed but somehow It doesn't work for the next. and show me this > Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ();

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks
Advance

Comment: The HTTP status code 400 means that you made an invalid request to the API endpoint. Without having seen any source code yet it would seem that the request you're making to Firebase is not valid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. In my case following trick solved the problem.
Try to use strong password with more than 6 characters while signing up
you can see the error by writing this code

```
return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user)=>{
            console.log(user)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
```

this was showing  in my case while signing up with password having less than 6 characters : `FirebaseError: Firebase: Password should be at least 6 characters (auth/weak-password).